# java linked list copy constructor and constructor from string

Tags: java, constructor, linked-list

I have 2 questions about linked lists so i figured i'll post them in one question.

first i'll show my node class and the copy constructor and constructor from a string

```
class CharNode 
{ 

   private char letter; 
   private CharNode next; 

   public CharNode(char ch, CharNode link) 
    { 
    letter = ch;
    next = link;
   }

   public void setCharacter(char ch) 
    { 
    letter = ch;
    }

   public char getCharacter() 
    {
    return letter;
    } 

    public void setNext(CharNode next) 
    {
    this.next = next;
    } 

   public CharNode getNext() 
    {
    return next;
    } 

}
```

copy constructor

```
   // copy constructor  
   public CharList(CharList l) 
{
    CharNode pt = head;

    while(pt.getNext() != null)
    {
        this.setCharacter() = l.getCharacter();
        this.setNext() = l.getNext();
    }
}
```

constructor from string

```
   // constructor from a String 
   public CharList(String s) 
{ 
    head = head.setCharacter(s);


}
```

when i try to compile i get an error for my copy constructor it says that it cant find the symbol `this.setCharacter()`... and the `l.setCharacter()`...

am i just doing it completely wrong?

and with my constructor from a string i know thats wrong. i thought about using the `charAt()` but how would i know when to stop the loop to do that? is that a good approach to take?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have received answers for 7 questions to date and not accepted any of the answers.  You will find that people are less inclined to help if you do not accept good answers.

Comment: you have to read a bit about the concept of encapsulation , if you do u'll resolve the compilation problemes yourself

Comment: you have to accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

in your CharList constructor, `this` refers to the `CharList` class, which doesn't have a `setCharacter()` method (CharNode does).  also, when you call a method in java, you need to pass the parameter, e.g. `setFoo(newFoo)`, not `setFoo() = newFoo`

Comment: can i say something like CharNode.setCharacter(paramater)?

Comment: that's the basic idea, although you would generally be working with an instance of CharNode, not the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your set character method is probably in your node, not in your list. You also need to be moving your pointer along. What I mean is, where do you ever "go to the next node"?

Answer (score 0):

Your copy constructor is for the class `CharList`, while `setCharacter` is defined in `CharNode`.

`this` in the copy constructor references the current instance of the CharList object the constructor is defined on.  `l` is also a `CharList` in your code rather than a `CharNode` which defines `setCharacter`.

The copy constructor should be defined in the `CharNode` class.

Answer (score 0):

In your "copy constructor" you would need to go through the list being passed in starting with its head, and create new nodes for your new list ...

```
public CharList(CharList l) 
{
    // Whatever method your CharList provides to get the 
    // first node in the list goes here
    CharNode pt = l.head(); 

    // create a new head node for *this* list
    CharNode newNode = new CharNode();
    this.head = newNode;

    // Go through old list, copy data, create new nodes 
    // for this list.
    while(pt != null)
    {
        newNode.setCharacter(pt.getCharacter());
        pt = pt.getNext();
        if (pt != null)
        {
            newNode.setNext(new CharNode());
            newNode = newNode.getNext();
        }

    }
}
```

As for creating a list from a `String` ... same concept except you iterate through the string rather than another `CharList`

```
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++)
{ 
    ...
    newNode.setCharacter(myString.charAt(i));
    ...
```

Comment: strings have lengths? is it like an array has length?

Comment: string is array of characters.

Comment: i have to create a new charnode inside the constructor, is that right?

Comment: @alexthefourth - Yes, the `String` object provides a `length()` method. You may want to read the javadoc to see all the other things it has as well. As for your second question, well ... yes. How else would you construct a new list? The above code is complete and would create a new CharList object with the same contents as the one passed in. You would construct a new list from a string in the same way.